# Laravel Crypt::decrypt breaks json serialize when there are duplicate entries in the DB

Tags: php, json, laravel

So I've got a pretty simple JSON API built in Laravel. The endpoint just returns an array of "applicant" objects. However, applicants have an SSN, so we're using Crypt::encrypt / Crypt::decrypt in the Accessor/mutator like so:

```
public function getSsnAttribute($value)
{
    return \Crypt::decrypt($value);
}

/**
 * MUTATORS
 */
public function setSsnAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['ssn'] = \Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```

This works just fine, and I get JSON dumped out of the object. However, as soon as there are two entries with the same SSN, it breaks, and I get back the error

```
file: "/Users/ryantrattles/Documents/sites/ftl-app-tracker/app-tracker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php"
line: 50
message: "Failed calling Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::jsonSerialize()"
```

I have no idea why this is happening and can't seem to find any documentation on Crypt that would indicate it would futz with json. The way I'm returning my models is simply

```
$leases = \Lease::with('primaryApplicant')->with('dealer')->get();
return $leases;
```

I can work around this by just not returning SSN here and fetching it separately (which I should do anyhow). But I'm more curious as to what's going on to cause this error here.

Comment: I believe that the mutators are used to convert the models to json. I can't imagine why the duplicate ssn would be a factor. Is it somehow being used as a primary key in the collection?

Comment: @CollinJames SSN is not a key in any way. Here is the migration for the column:

     $table->string('ssn', 216);


When I have 1 person in my DB, it works fine. If I add a second with the same SSN, it breaks and I get the json serialize error.  If I comment out the Crypt::decrypt() accessor for SSN, it works fine again (though doesn't return SSN as it's been encrypted). So it seems that the error is clearly attached to Crypt, and I can only produce it when I have duplicate SSN entries in my db :/

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in interface named `JsonSerializable`.  If an object implements this interface, PHP will call the defined `jsonSerialize` class to figure out what data structure needs to be returned by `json_encode`.  Consider the following code.

```
<?php

class A
{
    protected $foo='bar';
}

class B implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $foo='bar';
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return ['baz'];
    }
}

$test = new A;
echo json_encode($test),"\n";
$test = new B;
echo json_encode($test),"\n";
```

This `JsonSerializable` interface is how Laravel turns many of its objects into JSON.  There is one weird bit of behavior to this feature -- if you throw an exception in `jsonSerialize`, PHP will actually throw **two** exceptions.  If you try the following

```
class C implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $foo='bar';
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        throw new Exception("This is a test");
    }
}

$object = new C;
json_encode($object);
```

You'll get the following **two** exceptions

```
Next exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed calling C::jsonSerialize()' in /path/to/laravel/test2.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/laravel/test2.php(0): json_encode()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/laravel/test2.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This is a test' in /path/to/laravel/test2.php on line 12

Exception: This is a test in /path/to/laravel/test2.php on line 7

Call Stack:
    0.0009     238864   1. {main}() /path/to/laravel/test2.php:0
    0.0010     239728   2. json_encode() /path/to/laravel/test2.php:12
    0.0010     240000   3. C->jsonSerialize() /path/to/laravel/test2.php:12
```

So, in addition to the actual exception thrown, you'll also get the

> Failed calling Classname::jsonSerialize exception

exception.

If you're using Laravel 5 and you're loading the API URL in a browser, try scrolling down and you should see the second, "real" exception.

Also, try calling `jsonSerialize` directly.  This should also throw the real exception.  This will let you know what the real problem is, and should make tracking down the issue easier.

```
$leases = \Lease::with('primaryApplicant')->with('dealer')->get();
$leases->jsonSerialize();
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the detailed response. I'm unfortunately getting this at random times using Laravel 4.2 and even the class that supposedly causes this exception, when I call $obj->jsonSerialize() myself, I get the array back as expected. Any idea what could cause this?